# creating a batch file for programs to start using a delay

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file which starts some programs automatically with a delay. because it takes forever for my pc to start and i also get the unresponsiveness because of it.

this is how it looks like right now:

```
@echo off
TIMEOUT 5
start D:\somepath\someapp.exe
TIMEOUT 50
start "E:\somepath\someapp.exe"
```

because the last line is surrounded with quotation marks, the 'someapp.exe' didnt got started.

can someone explain why it didnt start the app? the first one however, did got started up.

also, how can i hide the command prompt?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `help start`. The first quoted argument is treated by `start` as the command window title. So your quoted `"E:\somepath\someapp.exe"` was the tile of an empty command window. Where as unquoted `E:\somepath\someapp.exe` was an actual command.

If you need to quote the command, use another quoted string first as the window title.

```
start "Someapp Window Title" "E:\somepath\someapp.exe"
```

Or if you don't want to provide a window title,  provide the path and command separately with /D switch

```
start /D "E:\somepath" someapp.exe
```

You can use the /B switch to stop creating a new window to start the command

```
start /D "E:\somepath" /B someapp.exe
```

Or you can use the /MIN switch to start the window minimized

```
start /D "E:\somepath" /MIN someapp.exe
```

Comment: i read somewhere that if the path has spaces, i need to surround it with quotes. but what about hiding the window?

Comment: yes you have to quote a directory name with spaces. then either you provide a window title or provide path and command separately.

Comment: to provide a directory name where the command (someapp.exe) is located

Comment: ok the /b is interesting. i saw the command prompt starting a new cmd window. so the /b switch prevents this right? and what do you mean with the /min switch? what exactly starts minimized? the cmd itself? or the programs i start?

Comment: `start` by default opens a new command window to run the command. `/MIN` will start this new window minized. `/B` will not open a new window, instead it will run the command within the current command window from where the `start` is being called.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by hiding command prompt. How do  you execute your batch file? if you do it from `start->run` use the command `cmd /c batchfilename.bat` then the command window will terminate after executing the batch file.